# Emacs - Getting PgDn to End of Buffer

Tags: emacs, scroll

I'm fairly new to Emacs, and I was wondering how to get the PageDown key to function so that it will send the point to the end of the buffer on the last PageDown instead of just printing "End of Buffer" in the minibuffer.

If there is some kind of benefit to keeping this behavior as-is, that would be interesting and helpful information as well.

Comment: I knew about this before asking, but it looks like it moves the mark to the buffer end.  I'm really just trying to tweak PgDn to have it do what I expect if I do happen to get to the end of the buffer.

Comment: What I meant was, you can use PgDn all the way until you're almost at the end, and then M-> to go all the way. PgDn is bound to a *scroll* command, not to a jump command, so it makes sense that it does not scroll any further when the end of the buffer is already in sight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `scroll-error-top-bottom` to a non-nil value, either via `M-x customize-variable RET scroll-error-top-bottom`, or by adding the following line to your `init.el`:

```
(setq scroll-error-top-bottom t)
```

From `C-h v scroll-error-top-bottom`:

> Move point to top/bottom of buffer before signaling a scrolling error.
>   A value of nil means just signal an error if no more scrolling possible.
>   **A value of t means point moves to the beginning or the end of the buffer
>   (depending on scrolling direction) when no more scrolling possible.**
>   When point is already on that position, then signal an error.

This is the standard solution without CUA or key remapping.

Answer (score 1):

The `cua` mode provides a `cua-scroll-up` command which does this. There are several ways to use it:

1. activate `cua-selection-mode`, to get not only this scrolling behaviour, but also a large number of improvements in CUA. This is the solution I would recommand. Just put this in your init file (`.emacs` or `.emacs.d/init.el`) :

   ```lisp
   (cua-selection-mode +1)
   ```
2. import only the scrolling behaviour from cua:

   ```lisp
   (require 'cua-base)
   (global-set-key [remap scroll-up]   'cua-scroll-up)
   (global-set-key [remap scroll-down] 'cua-scroll-down)
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  Unfortunately, I'm new enough to emacs that I haven't looked at or tried Cua mode before.

Comment: @mellowmaroon You should be aware that CUA mode changes key bindings beyond just scrolling.

Comment: @lunaryorn `cua-selection-mode` changes only scrolling and rectangle selection behaviour. Eveything else is left untouched. But you're right: the full CUA mode changes pretty much everything (which is why I wouldn't recommend it)

Comment: @Francesco Oh, sorry, I missed the cua-**selection**-mode part.  Forget my comment…